# typescript how to unwrap/remove Promise from a type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

i have a function that accepts an object where each prop is a promise. it waits for all the promise to finish then returns a new object with the same props but now resolved values.

[image]

`resolved_props.company` should be `string`, not `Promise<string>`

```
// TODO: fix the types on this
function promise_props<T>(obj:T):Promise<T> {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj)
  const len = keys.length
  const awaitables = new Array<T>(len)
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) awaitables[i] = (obj as any)[keys[i]]

  return Promise.all(awaitables).then((results) => {
    const byName:any = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) byName[keys[i]] = results[i]
    return byName
  })
}
```

Comment: You need to install `typescript@next` or wait for TypeScript 2.8 to be released. It will bring conditional types which allows to [unwrap a promise type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your types are not accurate enough and the TypeScript compiler cannot figure it out that they are not promises at that point.

What you need is something like this:

```
async function promise_props<T>(obj: {[key: string]: Promise<T>}): Promise<{[key: string]: T}> {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    const awaitables = keys.map(key => obj[key]);

    const values = await Promise.all(awaitables);
    const result: {[key: string]: T} = {};

    keys.forEach((key, i) => {
        result[key] = values[i];
    });
    return result;
}
```

But it will only work if your object has promises of the same type, for example:

```
{
    company: Promise.resolve("company"),
    page: Promise.resolve("1")
};
```

I'm not sure if it is possible to get it working with various promise types in the current TypeScript version, but as Tao also suggested, you can use the new features in TypeScript 2.8 to get it working:

```
type UnPromisifiedObject<T> = {[k in keyof T]: UnPromisify<T[k]>}
type UnPromisify<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T;

async function promise_props<T extends {[key: string]: Promise<any>}>(obj: T): Promise<UnPromisifiedObject<T>> {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    const awaitables = keys.map(key => obj[key]);

    const values = await Promise.all(awaitables);
    const result = {} as any;

    keys.forEach((key, i) => {
        result[key] = values[i];
    });
    return result as UnPromisifiedObject<T>;
}

async function main() {
    const x = {
        company: Promise.resolve("company"),
        page: Promise.resolve(1)
    };
    const res = await promise_props(x);
    const company = res.company;  // company is a string here
    const page = res.page;        // page is a number here
}
```

As you can see, the return type is properly inferred. I think the implementation of the method can be improved. I couldn't find a way to instantiate an instance of the return type and use `any`, but although compiler cannot infer it, it's type safe as we resolve all promises.

Comment: the 2.8 version works! thanks for writing it for me because it's pretty complicated.. i couldn't figure it out

Comment: @StephenBugsKamenar I was playing around again with this example, I think my first answer was not quite correct. In particular, I think the definition `promise_props<T>(obj: {[k in keyof T]: Promise<T[k]>})` was not good, because it was wrapping a promise inside promise if we consider `T[k]` was also a promise. Now I've updated it. It's simpler and uses the same implementation as the 2.7 version. I will give it another shot when 2.8 is officially out.

Comment: I'm stuck in typescript v4.2.4 that doesn't have the built-in `Awaited` type. I used your `UnPromisify` renamed into `Awaited` and worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 58):

#### Typescript 4.5

Utility type `Awaited` is officially built in typescript v4.5.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5/#awaited-type

```
// A = string
type A = Awaited<Promise<string>>;

// B = number
type B = Awaited<Promise<Promise<number>>>;

// C = boolean | number
type C = Awaited<boolean | Promise<number>>;
```

Comment: About time TS!!! thanks!

Comment: Neat! This should be the accepted answer now.

Comment: And if for some reason you are not able to upgrade to TypeScript 4.5+, you could use `Awaited` from the ts-essentials package: `import { Awaited } from "ts-essentials"`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-essentials#awaited-type

Answer (score 14):

after typescript 2.8, i was able to use the following strategy

```
export type Await<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T
export type AwaitProps<T> = {[P in keyof T]: Await<T[P]>}

export async function concurrent<T>(obj: T): Promise<AwaitProps<T>> {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj)
    const awaitables = keys.map(key => obj[key])
    const values = await Promise.all(awaitables)
    const result = {}
    keys.forEach((key, i) => result[key] = values[i])
    return <AwaitProps<T>>result
}
```

and the usage looks like this

```
const {claimRow, profileRow} = await concurrent({
    claimRow: claimTable.one(identify(userId)),
    profileRow: profileTable.one(identify(userId)),
})
```