# Typescript: automagically strip Promise<> from types?

Tags: typescript

I have an internal representation of a data model that looks similar to this:

```
class InternalDataClass {
    propOne?: Promise<string>;
    propTwo?: Promise<number>;
    propThree?: string;
    ...
}
```

Some properties are Promise since they're populated by async processes. However, being that this is a web service, I'd like to expose this structure to clients in its wire form (obviously without Promises). Like this:

```
class ExternalDataClass {
    propOne?: string;
    propTwo?: string;
    propThree?: string;
}
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this in Typescript without having to redeclare everything? This is especially pertinent in my case since, yes, my illustration here only has 3 properties, but you can imagine a data class getting significantly larger!

Thanks!
tim

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944552/typescript-how-to-unwrap-remove-promise-from-a-type - `UnPromisifiedObject`/`UnPromisify` seems like a good candidate.

Comment: Is it acceptable `ExternalDataClass` to be a type alias and not a class?

Comment: @Caramiriel, this is a little bit different since this involves unwrapping (i.e. fully resolving) any Promise<T> properties on an object. I actually do something similar in my web service before putting the data on the wire. But I was purely looking for a way to define a type for use by clients. The answer below does that perfectly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a conditional type to "unpack" the promise:

```
class InternalDataClass {
    propOne?: Promise<string>;
    propTwo?: Promise<number>;
    propThree?: string;
}

type UnpackAny<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U: T
type UnpackProperties<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: UnpackAny<T[P]>
}

type ExtrnalInterface = UnpackProperties<InternalDataClass>
// type ExtrnalInterface = {
//     propOne?: string | undefined;
//     propTwo?: number | undefined;
//     propThree?: string | undefined;
// }
```

If you really want to create a class instead of just a type you can force implement the `ExtrnalInterface`:

```
class ExtrnalDataClass extends (class { } as new () => ExtrnalInterface) {

}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=18&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECSB2AXApgJ3mEARMiwGFwpoBvAWAChproAHVAe1oHl5kB+ALmgAVGBbAJYRkAHgiJUg+AHMAfAG5KNOo1oAVAO4MuvAcLHwArvwBGaRcpr0m6gBapkHbhKmylFAL6VKiAJ60yNAAqvCmDAAeAILwfqLqctAAvNDq0MgRKPAAJjB8DEIiotIAZmghiewh3Oq+AUGh4RH5gaiIgsgQ8Ykp5FQ0ANo80NLQANbIfgwlqQC63I2RMXHqQ7NylN4UdYHQAKKZ6JgIKKglYMBBKYvNamjtnaInaBjYuAREEBsUAPQ-0P5dgdJK9nmcLldSJQ-ipVExWM5oK5pDJoAAfaBGHLIErSZDZDwwlQ2DTaXTGMzlDFY7I4vEE6H-YlqeyORHI2TozHY3FsBm-f5bUCQGDAo5vPCEEXpTLIHIwAAUwuIJGgnmgkGgbE00AVAEpkokxaCkGhzpcDX0VJtKNr9odXjhJZ99QA6EkIgCErtMghk+oUQA)

Comment: Awesome! I knew there had to be some Typescript trickery to make that happen! Thanks so much!